# How to delete autoforwarded email in SENT folder Outlook 2010 Exchange

Tags: vba, email, outlook

Newbie poster with Outlook VBA. Intermediate Excel VBA coder.

I have a VBA routine that autoforwards all incoming email to a Gmail account. It is not all my code, (modified from a blog post) but it works. I need to keep a copy of all my email received in all my accounts so I can consolidate them into one main one. In the Outlook 2010 Exchange account, all the forwarded mail gets saved in the SENT folder as a copy.

Is it possible to delete the autoforwarded copy in the SENT folder, without deleting all SENT emails? I need to keep the emails I actually respond to.

I would not have a problem using conversation mode in the INBOX, to store the replied to emails. but as it now stands, everything is duplicated due to the bcc copy in the SENT folder when I toggle Conversation mode for the INBOX.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
        Dim objRecip As Recipient
        Dim strMsg As String
        Dim res As Integer
        Dim strBcc As String
        On Error Resume Next

        ' #### USER OPTIONS ####
        ' address for Bcc -- must be SMTP address or resolvable
        ' to a name in the address book
        strBcc = "bcc.hwb@gmail.com"

        Set objRecip = Item.Recipients.Add(strBcc)
        objRecip.Type = olBCC
        If Not objRecip.Resolve Then
            strMsg = "Could not resolve the Bcc recipient. " & _
                     "Do you want still to send the message?"
            res = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, _
                    "Could Not Resolve Bcc Recipient")
            If res = vbNo Then
                Cancel = True
            End If
        End If

        Set objRecip = Nothing
    End Sub

Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
    Dim varEntryIDs
    Dim objItem
    Dim myItem As MailItem
    Dim i As Integer
    varEntryIDs = Split(EntryIDCollection, ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(varEntryIDs)
        Set objItem = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(varEntryIDs(i))
        'MsgBox (varEntryIDs(i))

        Set myItem = objItem.Forward
        myItem.Recipients.Add "bcc.hwb@gmail.com"
        myItem.Send

        'myItem.Delete

        Set myItem = Nothing
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [MailItem.DeleteAfterSubmit Property (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868585.aspx)

```
myItem.DeleteAfterSubmit = True
```

Comment: Thanks for this - where in the code should it be placed?   after  myItem.Recipients.Add "bcc.hwb@gmail.com"  or  after myItem.Send?

Comment: Between Set myItem = objItem.Forward and myItem.Send